# How can I get rid of the commas and brackets in an arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm trying to figure out how I can have someone input strings and then have them print out with only a space separating each string in Java.  It would also be helpful if you could also help me figure out how to get rid of the "end" in the output of it as well.  Here is the code I have so far

```
            Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter 'End' to quit");

            ArrayList<String> firstString = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i = 0; i <= 9999; i++)
            {
                firstString.replaceAll(String::toLowerCase);

                if(firstString.contains("end"))
                {
                    Collections.sort(firstString);

                    break;
                }
                else
                firstString.add(s.nextLine());
            }

            String firstStringOut = firstString.toString();

            firstStringOut.replace(",", "");

            System.out.println(firstStringOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like homework

Comment: Easy: don't convert it to a string with `firstString.toString()`.

Comment: but then how do I get rid of the brackets and commas??

Comment: `firstStringOut.replace(",", "");` doesn't change the string.

Comment: `firstStringOut.replace(",", "");` has to be assigned to something

Comment: @MalteHartwig looks like you are not common with `replace` and `replaceAll`. They actually do the same and their only difference is that `replaceAll` takes a regex as parameter instead of a `CharSequence`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Terribly sorry, my bad. Removed the wrong statement about replace and replaceAll. Still want to point out to be careful with starting with `Collection.toString()` and removing commas. It can lead to unforeseen side effects if your elements' `toString` representations contain commas.

Comment: Rather than adding all lines blindly to the list and then checking the whole list after each line, check each line as it's entered and don't add it to the list if it's "end" but exit the loop instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your last 3 lines of code with this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String str : firstString) {
        if (!str.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
            sb.append(str);
            sb.append(" ");
        } else {
            sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(" "));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

It will build a string of everything you added to the list and upon printing, it shows each value separated by a space (also ignores "end").

Or you just chain the replacements or create a proper regex like this:

```
firstStringOut = firstStringOut.replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("end", "");
firstStringOut = firstStringOut.replaceAll(",|\\[|\\]|end", "");
```

All approaches work fine, but the first is the best to use IMO.